# How to remove annoying header and footer for some pages that are intentionally made landscape?

Tags: header-footer, landscape

I am writing a book where some tables need wider space. 
The only solution is to make the tables in intentionally-made landscape pages.

Unfortunately, there are annoying headers and footers on the landscape pages. How to remove those annoying header and footers?

The following is my "minimal" code snippet:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{longtable,array}

\begin{document}
\chapter{One}
\lipsum[1]
\section{One One}
\lipsum[2]

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}{|m{0.4\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1.5\fboxrule}|m{0.6\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1.5\fboxrule}|}
\hline
a & b\\\hline
c & d\\\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\pagestyle{plain}

\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

---

**EDIT 1:**

I made a correction in the column width, i.e., changing `2\fboxrule` to `1.5\fboxrule`. The former calculation is wrong because the rule between 2 columns should NOT be calculated twice. I slipped a little here.

---

**EDIT 2:**

Herbert's solution is the final answer.

Comment: Is your question still a question? It looks more like an answer now. You shouldn't give answers in questions, but rather post a separate answer.

Comment: @Hendrik, thanks for informing the rule. I will post the answer 15 minutes later. There are some adjustments based on Herbert's answers I must consider in the other topic I am reading.

Comment: Your edits 2 and 3 seem to contradict each other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{lscape}

\begin{document}
foo
\clearpage\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{landscape}

bar\clearpage baz
\end{landscape}
\pagestyle{plain}

next page

\end{document}
```

Comment: is it necessary to use `\clearpage` ?

Comment: sure! At the _end_ of an page TeX looks for the pagestyle. The reason why it cannot work without. In that case the `\pagestyle{empty}` is also used for the page before landscape.

Comment: I still can compile my code above (in question session) even though I don't use `\clearpage`.

Comment: delete in my example the `\clearpage` and you do not get a page number on the page before landscape.

Answer (score 5):

You want to use `\thispagestyle{empty}` on the pages that shouldn't have headers or footers.

**Edit:**

```
\begin{landscape}
\thispagestyle{empty}
% longtable code
\end{landscape}
```

Comment: @TH, thanks. If I use `\pagestyle{empty}` right before `\begin{landscape}` and `\pagestyle{plain}` right after `\end{landscape}`, is it correct?

Comment: @xport: If by, "is it correct?" you're asking if it works, the answer is I don't know. Did you try it? But why bother? `\thispagestyle{empty}` should work. If it doesn't please provide a _minimal_ example.

Comment: `\thispagestyle` does not work and I don't know how to use it. My way above works but I am not sure it is the correct way to do.

Comment: @xport: Then you need to provide a minimal example where it isn't working.

Comment: @TH, minimal code has been given above. I just updated several seconds ago.

Comment: @xport: It works for me. See my edit.

Comment: @TH, thanks. Your solution is simpler than mine. Upvoting for you. :-)

Comment: @TH, your solution just works for one page rather than some consecutive pages. So I should roll back  the GREEN mark only (upvote remains unchanged). :-) I am sorry.

Comment: @xport: Yes, it only changes it for a single page. You should accept your own answer then.

Comment: @TH, The best solution is @Herbert's :-)